# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_apple_darwin13_4_0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.x, pyenv

### Error

Here is the error that I get:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 544, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 550, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 421, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_apple_darwin13_4_0'
```

I am currently on a mac trying to run [this](https://github.com/bzamecnik/ml/tree/master/instrument-classification) Github Project.

---

### Background

I wanted to use both `Python2` and `Python3`. This is due to the fact that some of my projects still use `Python2`. In order to do this, I followed the steps in the website [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097). I proceeded to do this:

[image]

In order to change to this kernel, I did a simple `source activate py36` in my root folder. Then, I wanted to run a library through the call `python3 generate_chords.py`, but I get the error above.

---

### Python Environment

Note on the versions:

```
(py36) ~/D/C/m/instrument-classification ❯❯❯ python --version
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(py36) ~/D/C/m/instrument-classification ❯❯❯ python3 --version
Python 3.6.4
```